# Crop an existing imageview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a custom  layout with image view and button
when I click on the button the image present on the image view need to cropped custom based on the drag of rectangular box.

once the crop is done the image view should be replaced by cropped image

it is a custom layout with image view and button

Answer (score 2):

Use this lib: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

It's easy to use, clear description in his Github project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:  [Click Here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)!

this will works for you.

Android-Image-Cropper